# UIAutomation cannot access complete cell name

Tags: javascript, ios, instruments, xcode6, ios-ui-automation

So I'm having this problem and I found that this happens only with the new xcode 6 and the iOS 8 SDK.

Usually (on iOS 7) I could get the contents of the cell by only asking for the name of that cell, for instance:

```
var tableVIew = this.window().tableViews()[1];
var cellName = tableVIew.cells()[0].name();
```

For example if the contents of the cell was:

> 2014-09-19 another string concatenated with the date to display in
>   cell

Then the output of the cellName variable (in iOS 7) will be:

```
2014-09-19, another string concatenated with the date to display in cell
```

But with xcode 6 and the new iOS 8 SDK, instruments is only able to pick up the first instance of the cell i.e:

```
2014-09-19
```

It cannot pick up the second part of that cell at all.  So the only way for me to access that cell will be:

```
tableVIew.cells()["2014-09-19"];
```

Is there any way or workaround to get the full contents of the cell with xcode 6 and the iOS 8 SDK?

Any help or pointers will be helpful.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've found a workaround for this.

Instead of using only:

```
cells()[0].name();
```

I could access the text in the cell separately:

```
cells()[0].staticTexts()[1].name();
```

Which will return the name of the second element in the cell which would be (looking back at the example used in the question):

```
another string concatenated with the date to display in cell
```